# Selenium "send_keys" not importing

Tags: python, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do basic web automation in Python (Pycharm). I am running a test where I open up YouTube in Chrome and have the program type text into the search box and press "RETURN" to perform the search. It is able to perform all of these tasks, except for sending "RETURN". The text where I am trying to import the keys package always ends up greyed out. And I get an error message when I run everything saying:

searchbox.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
NameError: name 'keys' is not defined

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys('test')
searchbox.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
```

I have tried installing different key press packages using pip, but PyCharm always seems to not recognize them, even once I tell it to install them and it claims to install successfully. I had difficulty getting selenium to work with PyCharm at the start as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are having is that the package is called `Keys` not `keys`. Remember python is case sensitive. Please try:

```
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```